# Can't receive mail from outside

Tags: postfix

I have two domains hosted on my server and now I want to setup both domains for my mail server, but I'm stuck. Localy it works fine, but when it comes from outside (hotmail, gmail...) it doesn't work.

If I try to check my logs, nothing is happening. (`/var/log/mail.log` & `/var/log/mail.err`)

```
# DKIM
# --------------------------------------
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891

smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem

content_filter = scan:127.0.0.1:10026
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtp_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/add_x_header
```

and my master.cnf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin

spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
        user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}


smtp-amavis unix -      -       n     -       2  smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n    -       n       -       -     smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
    -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
```

Any suggestion based on this problem?

Comment: Try `telnet <your_mailserver_ip> 25` from outside and add output to your post

Comment: Connectivity looks ok. Do senders receive any bounce message that mail couldn't be delivired to your domain?

Comment: [What is the real domain name?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Comment: is `example.com` listed in `/etc/postfix/virtual_domains`? Or you just tried testing using `mxtoolbox`? on a side note,dont list the same domain name under `mydestination` and `relay_domains`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `MX` record to your DNS settings. Let's say your `mailserver` has IP `1.2.3.4`, you'd need to add in your `my.doomain.zone` file:

```
domain.com.   MX 10       mail.domain.com.
mail           A           1.2.3.4
```

Comment: is it possible to let us know the domain so we can verify that is setup correctly?

Comment: What does `nslookup -q=mx domain.com` outputs?

Comment: Are you using `SPF`?

Comment: Not related with the topic but you should use `-all` instead.